# ffmpeg how to record desktop video and audio in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to record desktop video and audio in windows 10 with ffmpeg.

I Use this command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Synaptics SmartAudio HD)" d:\output.mkv
```

but when I exit with q command from terminal I get this error:

```
[q] command received. Exiting.

[out#0/matroska @ 0000018ee98392c0] video:2862kB audio:186kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 0.357037%
frame=   82 fps=8.8 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3058kB time=00:00:18.00 bitrate=1391.3kbits/s speed=1.92x  
... 
[libx264 @ 0000018ee98a9200] ref P L0: 48.9%  7.8% 34.7%  8.6%
[libx264 @ 0000018ee98a9200] ref B L0: 73.7% 22.0%  4.3%
[libx264 @ 0000018ee98a9200] ref B L1: 94.2%  5.8%
[libx264 @ 0000018ee98a9200] kb/s:1283.08

Conversion failed!
```

and the video is jerky and no audio.R

The version of ffmpeg is:

```
ffmpeg version 2023-07-19-git-efa6cec759-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
```

and I enabled Stereo Mix in windows.

Any idea how i can fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried OBS https://obsproject.com/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/75618603/

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows 7, but the following should work on Windows 10.

Run List Devices script. Microphone must be plugged in.

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

The resulting cmd output should include information similar to below.

```
[dshow @ 0000000000177e00] Could not enumerate video devices (or none found).
[dshow @ 0000000000177e00] "Microphone (3- USB Microphone)" (audio)
[dshow @ 0000000000177e00]   Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD
43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone (3- USB Microphone)"
```

My microphone is listed as "Microphone (3- USB Microphone)"
Yours will of course be different.
Add this to the Screen Audio script as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (3- USB Microphone)" -f gdigrab -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 18 -preset superfast -c:a aac -ac 1 out.mkv
```

Output parameters can be adapted to suit.

If you want to delay recording after initiating, add the following above the Screen Audio script. Adjust time (in secs) to suit.

```
timeout /t 5
```

If there is a delay, or sync issue with video and audio, the following script can be used to correct.

```
ffmpeg -i out.mkv -itsoffset -0.6 -i out.mkv -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -c:a: copy -c:v copy output.mkv
```

Positive value:  Video forward (Audio backwards).
Minus value:     Video backwards (Audio forward).

Edit:

The following can be used to record video only:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 18 -preset veryfast out.mkv
```

Audio only:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (2- USB Microphone)" -c:a aac -ac 1 out.aac
```

Comment: Thanks tried with: ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Internal Microphone (Synaptics SmartAudio HD)" -f gdigrab -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -crf 18 -preset superfast -c:a aac -ac 1 d:\out .mkv but it always returns conversion error.

Comment: I've edited to add screen record only, and audio only. This may confirm if it is an issue with audio settings in Windows, or not