# How to change audio track in video and shift it with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to sync video and audio by adding a higher-quality audio file over a video file with ffmpeg without-encoding.

I need to do it by shifting audio and not video since I need the video exactly as it is.

Until now I have tried with:

- `adelay` filter, but it re-encodes audio
- `-ss` option but it does not support negative values
- `its offset` but it does not shift audio, or at least, it does something but it does noshiftif by the indicated milliseconds amount and I do not understand what it does exactly

My objective is to use video and audio as inputs and I want to delay or anticipate audio.

Has someone any idea?

Comment: Try my code for syncing audio from the following link...... https://superuser.com/questions/1802440/ffmpeg-how-to-record-desktop-video-and-audio-in-windows-10

Comment: @Sark I am using something similar but it doesn't work, specifically `ffmpeg -i in1_path - itsoffset offsetms -i in2_path -c:v mpeg4 -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 1:a -b:v 3M -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M out_path`

Comment: Why are you re-encoding the video source. The following works if you are just extracting video from one source, and audio from another... `ffmpeg -i vid_source.mp4 -itsoffset VALUE -i audio_source.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -c:a copy -c:v copy out.mp4`

Comment: @Sark I am re encoding because I need that codec in output anyway trying your command (with audio_source as a wav and so changing -map 1:0) it does not work

Comment: `itsoffset` value is in decimal seconds.

Comment: You need to edit your question to state precisely what inputs you are using,  and precisely what you want to do with them. I had assumed you were trying to swap one video sources audio with the audio from another video source. This is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Gyan what are decimal seconds?

Comment: x.yz e.g. `5.482`

Comment: @Gyan if that means ~ 5 seconds and a half, it did not change anything

Comment: How are you playing the output?

Comment: @Gyan I am verifying the audio shift with audacity by visually comparing the audio tracks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below output is .mkv as .mp4 does not support .wav.

```
fffmpeg -i input1.mov -itsoffset 0 -i input2.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v mpeg4 -b:v 3M -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M -c:a copy output.mkv
```

`-map 0:0 -map 1:0` should also work.

Comment: Not working (I am using `.mov` anyway, but it does not work with `.mkv` neither). At this moment I am using `-ss` and I am moving video track instead.

Comment: Above works for me. Can you copy and paste here your exact code, direct from notepad. Would like to see if I can simulate error.

Comment: MY ERROR. The auto spell correction changed bufsize to business without me realising. Have corrected.... Will have to see if this can be turned off. Not the first time it has caught me out. Also, Windows Media Player may not support .mov itsoffset settings. Test in a different player.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "BERIO100.mov" -itsoffset 4.760 -i "BERIO100.wav" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v mpeg4 -c:a copy out.mkv`

Comment: Have now read your response to Gyan. All becomes clear. The scripts are working, but your testing with audacity is deeply flawed. Audacity will never show the shift. You need to test in a Video Player. The audio is not "shifted". The itsoffset value just tells it to play at a different time in relation to the video streams timeline. Without playing the output in a video player, there is no video stream timeline.

Comment: Wow, thanks, this is unexpected, and really hard to test, is there a way to "apply" the changes? Also I have now to ask if it is compatible with all video players?

Comment: No guarantee that all hardware players offer full support, but most should. Most popular software players will offer support, but having said that, Windows Media Player failed with one of my tested files.... If you know the offset. Adding this as silence at the start of the audio in Audacity will give you a file that does not require shifting. Support should no longer be an issue.
 Because you are working with .wavs,   quality on export should also not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, is there a way to add silence with ffmpeg, but without re encoding?

Comment: Several ways are described fully here... https://superuser.com/questions/579008/add-1-second-of-silence-to-audio-through-ffmpeg#:~:text=Using%20the%20concat%20demuxer%20(add,or%20end%20(or%20both).&text=If%20you%20want%20the%20silence,of%20the%20files%20in%20input

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure about the shifting part, but at least everything else can be done with [Shutter Encoder](https://www.shutterencoder.com/en/) (most stuff even lossless). Shutter Encoder is an awesome GUI for ffmpeg.

[image: Shutter Encoder]